# How to insert a new value into a data-attribute array via text input which is wrapped by square bracket?

Tags: jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I have an element contain array like the code below
`<div class="home_team" data-home='["10","20","30"]'></div>`

When I enter value from input below, I want the value to be inserted into the array above.
`<input type="text" /><button class="update_home_timeline">update</button>`\

I manage to insert the value (let's say I entered 100) but some how it remove the square bracket and semi-colon around each of the data in the array and become like code below 
`<div class="home_team" data-home="10,20,30100"></div>`

The JS

```
   $('.update_home_timeline').on('click', function () {
        newInput = $(this).prev().val();
        $('.home_team').attr('data-home', dataHome + newInput);
    });
```

How to make it not to remove the square bracket and semi colon like the code sample below?
`<div class="home_team" data-home='["10","20","30","100"]'></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [];
var total = [];
$('.update_home_timeline').on('click', function() {
  arr = [];
  newInput = $(this).prev().val();
  var str = $('.home_team').attr('data-home')
  var res = str.split(",");
  arr.push(newInput);
  var total = res.concat(arr);
    var x = total.toString();
  $('.home_team').attr('data-home', x);
  console.log('updated-data-in-element-data-home', $('.home_team').attr('data-home'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home_team" data-home="10,20,30,100"></div>
<input type="text" /><button class="update_home_timeline">update</button>
```

You can do it like this.
Did a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/h9rktxuz/21/